# Mocha "cannot find module" error

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, package.json

node v6.10.2, npm v3.10.3, mocha v3.1.2

my package.json has this in the scripts section:

`"test": "mocha ./test/unit/* --recursive"`

When I run `npm test` I get

```
> @hc/pos-onlineordering@0.1.0 test C:\_dev\pos-onlineordering\server
> mocha ./test/unit/* --recursive "--reporter" "dot"

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\_dev\app\server\test\unit\deploy'
```

it just so happens that C:_dev\app\server\test\unit\deploy is a directory holding several test files in it.

Here's where it gets really fun though. If I enter `mocha ./test/unit/* --recursive` at the command prompt, it runs all the tests like I would expect. I need it to run as a package script because the running the unit tests are a part of the build and deploy scripts.

More weird: It works for every other team member, some on Macs, some on Windows. I've tried it in Windows Power Shell and in Git-Bash, running as an administrator.

I have deleted the node_modules folder and re-run npm install. I have also run 
`npm uninstall -D mocha && npm i -D mocha` and nothing changes. I have even deleted the entire repository and re-cloned it.

So my assumption is that I clearly have something wrong with my computer or environment, but I don't even know where to look for what it could be at this point. How can I get mocha to run out of the package scripts?